# Paypal adaptive payment (parallel) 550001 error

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I did PayPal adaptive parallel payment using PAY API in which whatever user(buyer) purchase suppose user purchased items of total $100.
In my adaptive parallel payment there is 2 receiver :Receiver1 and Receiver2 and both will get 50-50 % from total amount. 
so total Amount of Receiver1 is : : $50 and 
total Amount of Receiver2 is : : $50

i have also registerd my app at :https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications and obtained LIveID which is automatically approved.

it all works fine in Sandbox enviorment but when I go to live it will give me following error
[0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 550001
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => User is not allowed to perform this action
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

i did research on it  and i got answer that Business account has to verified, is it compulsory to verify business account??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Adaptive Parallel Payment, the application owner (API Caller) must have a Preferred account type with PayPal (either Premier Verified or Business Verified Account). If the other receiver is not yet registered with PayPal, he will receive an email explaining how to complete/claim the payment.

Comment: Thank you PayPal_Federica it works :) and i havent enough reputaion so i cant able to vote up your answer.